# Is "surjective" missing in this exercise's wording?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

In an exercise I am asked to prove the following:

> Prove that a continuous image of a path-connected space is path-connected.

So the first thing that came to mind was:

Let $f:(X,\tau) \to (Y,\tau_1)$ be continuous, and $(X,\tau)$ path connected. Then let $a,b \in Y$ such that $a \neq b$. Then let $a'\in f^{-1}(\{a\})$ and $b' \in f^{-1}(\{b\})$ such that $a' \neq b'.$ Because $(X,\tau)$ is path-connected there exists a path from $a'$ to $b'$ and then what I thought is based on that prove that there exists a path from $a$ to $b$. ´

But my question is: How do I know that $\exists a' \in X: f(a')= 0$, because we don't know if our function is surjective or not. Previously the book stated the following propertie:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau_1)$ be topological spaces and $f(X,\tau) \to(Y,\tau_1)$ **surjective** and continuous. If $(X,\tau)$ is connected then $(Y,\tau_1)$ is also connected.

Is the exercise that I'm trying to solve badly formulated or is indeed correct and the function does not need to be surjective?

Comment: "continuous image" means that you should consider $f(X)$ rather than the whole of $Y$ (or add surjective as you suggested, which is the same)

Comment: The key word is *image*. One is not trying to prove $Y$ is path-connected, rather than the image of $f$, viz., $f(X)$, is path-connected.

Comment: The image of $f$ is $f(X)$ while the codomain of $f$ is $Y.$ So the  question could be reframed as “If $f$ is surjective, then $Y$ is path-connected.”

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted it then. My apologies  @AnginaSeng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is *not* to prove that $Y$ is path-connected. Rather, it is to prove that $f(X)$ is path-connected. And then your approach works. That is, if $a,b\in f(X)$, there are $a',b'\in X$ such that $f(a')=a$ and thet $f(b')=b$. If $\gamma$ is a path in $X$ that goes from $a'$ to $b'$, then $f\circ\gamma$ is a path in $f(X)$ that goes from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: So when they say the "image" they are talking about $f(X)$ with the topology induced by $Y$ (the codomain)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães note that they could have formulated the connectedness fact in the way: the continuous image of a connected space is connected. Then you also omit the (implicit) surjectivity.